# Error message when trying to pass data from component to page in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've created a component in Nuxt to get data from a Firestore database and would like to show that data in a page I created.

When I embed the component in a page I keep getting the error:

Property or method "provinces" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Now, when I copy the code from the component in the page it works just fine, so I assume the problem is with passing the data between the component and the page.

Full code of the component in components/index.vue :

```
  <template>
      <section class="container">
        <div class="index">
          <div v-for="province in provinces" :key="province.id">
        <div class="div_title">
          <h2>{{ province.name_nl }}</h2>
        </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </template>

<script>
// import { VueperSlides, VueperSlide } from 'vueperslides'
// import 'vueperslides/dist/vueperslides.css'
import firebase from 'firebase'
// import fireDb from '@/plugins/firebase.js'
export default {
  name: 'Index',
  components: {
    //  VueperSlides,
    //  VueperSlide
  },
  data: function() {
    return {}
  },

  async asyncData() {
    const moment = require('moment')
    const date = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    const housesArray = []
    const provincesArray = []

    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('provinces')
      .orderBy('name_nl')
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          provincesArray.push(doc.data())
        })
      })

    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('houses')
      .where('valid_until', '>', date)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          housesArray.push(doc.data())
        })
      })

    return {
      provinces: provincesArray,
      houses: housesArray
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
div {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 95vh;
}
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
p {
  text-align: left;
}
li {
  min-width: 100% !important;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

Page where I insert the component in pages/index.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-layout column justify-center align-center>
    <v-flex xs12 sm8 md6>
      <div class="text-xs-center">
        <logo />
        <tabs />
        <index />
      </div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
import Logo from '~/components/Logo.vue'
import Tabs from '~/components/Tabs.vue'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import Index from '~/components/Index.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Logo,
    Tabs,
    Index
  },
  data: function() {
    return {}
  }
}
    </script>
```

I would expect the page to display the data that I retrieved when I import the component into the page but I keep getting the same error.

Should I be using the Nuxt store to transfer data between a component and a page or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifecycle hook `asyncData` is not know within Vue components. It's only known in Nuxt pages.

It's better to do the data request within your pages component and pass it as a property to your component:

pages/index.vue

```
<template>
   <index :houses="houses" />
</template>
<script>
const delay = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time)); 

export default {
   async asyncData() {
     // fake data
     await delay(500);

     return {
       houses: [...]
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

components/index.vue

```
<template>
  <pre>{{ houses }}</pre>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   props: {
      houses: {
        required: true,
        type: Array
      }
   }
}
</script>
```